# Looping through different images in multiple folders in google colab and converting image format from one to other

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision

[As shown in the image: The 11 folders in train1_set has 600 images each. I want to convert its format from png to jpg of all images and save them to Train_jpg in similar format. For that i have already crated 11 empty folders in Train_jpg with corresponding names same as that in train1_set.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNIuY.png)

**For this task i have written the below code:**

```
folder_path = '/tmp/characters/train1_set'
for fldr in os.listdir(folder_path):
    sub_folder_path = os.path.join(folder_path, fldr)
    for filee in os.listdir(sub_folder_path):
        file_path = os.path.join(sub_folder_path, filee)
        im = Image.open(file_path)
        rgb_im = im.convert('RGB')
        rgb_im.save('/tmp/Train_jpg/{}/{}.jpg'.format(fldr,filee.split('.')[0]))
```

**But i am getting error:**

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-ea4ef81a0e50> in <module>()
      7         im = Image.open(file_path)
      8         rgb_im = im.convert('RGB')
----> 9         rgb_im.save('/tmp/Train_jpg/{}/{}.jpg'.format(fldr,filee.split('.')[0]))
     10 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py in save(self, fp, format, **params)
   2097                 fp = builtins.open(filename, "r+b")
   2098             else:
-> 2099                 fp = builtins.open(filename, "w+b")
   2100 
   2101         try:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/Train_jpg/ગ/aakar-medium_38_ગ_15.jpg'
```

**Please help me resolve my issue. Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes in your code which I have corrected.
You are getting the error because `filee` does not have the correct path.
**Code:**

```
import os
from PIL import Image
folder_path = '/tmp/characters/train1_set'
target_path = '/tmp/Train_jpg'
for fldr in os.listdir(folder_path):
    sub_folder_path = os.path.join(folder_path, fldr)
    if fldr not in os.listdir(target_path):
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(target_path,fldr))
    for filee in os.listdir(sub_folder_path):
        file_path = os.path.join(sub_folder_path, filee)
        im = Image.open(file_path)
        rgb_im = im.convert('RGB')
        rgb_im.save('data/img1/{}/{}.jpg'.format(fldr,filee.split('.')[0]))
```

Comment: Hey i ran your code! But its still throwing the foll error:                                                          
                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                       FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/Train_jpg/ગ/aakar-medium_38_ગ_15.jpg'

Comment: Can you update your question with the error? It is difficult to read and understand the error in the comments. Also, add complete Traceback.

Comment: It seems you have not used my exact code. Copy my exact code and execute it. You have not added `sub_folder_path` as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: i did it now. Have a look

Comment: Have your created a directory named `ગ` inside your `Train_jpg` directory. The code expects you to create 11 empty directories inside `Train_jpg` with exact same name.

Comment: Yes i have created all 11 directories in side Train_jpg. Look i added that screenshot too in the question.

Comment: Your folder is named `Train_jgp` not `Train_jpg`.